# FileNotFoundException for a .net core class library while referenced in a .net core console app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to use my custom .net core class library inside a .net core (Console) app. So the .net core class library referenced without any issues as the intelliscense shows up my methods defined in class library but the build fails throwing this exception.

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or 
>   assembly 'REF_CLS_LIB, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

**Target Framework :** netcoreapp1.1
**Editor :** Visual studio community 2017

Note. *I do not want to use my class library via nuget package manager.*

Comment: Is the assembly copied to the target directory?

Comment: I just referenced it like we import normal .dll file in .net projects so what do you mean by target directory ?

Comment: Referencing dll files will be supported with the upcoming 2.0.0 tools / VS 2017 15.3 update.

Comment: Martin! what do you mean by 2.0.0 tools ?

Comment: .NET Core CLI 2.0.0 and the VS update, both not yet released. See GH issue https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/120

Comment: It's worth noting .NET Core 2.0.0 is in beta and you can get the CLI and VS Tools if you're on VS 2017 Preview. https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/preview#windowscmd